# Saving files locally after uploading a file

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, vue.js

I'm trying to use this method I found online to upload a file and then after clicking submit to download it to a path somewhere in my project, I will post the code from my frontend, in the backend I'm using Java Spring, I need to use a controller somehow I guess, but I have no idea what to do.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell">
      <label>File
        <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()"/>
      </label>
        <button v-on:click="submitFile()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

submitFile() {

  const formData = new FormData().append('file', this.file)
  axios.post('/api/download',
    formData,
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }
  ).then(function() {
    console.log('SUCCESS!!')
  })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log('FAILURE!!')
    })
}
```

Comment: do you have access to the backend? what is your server env`?

Comment: Please be more specific. Where do you have problems? With sending the file from the frontend? or with receiving it in the backend? or both? Generally speaking you have to send the file in a http post to your backend. Your backend needs to take the incoming data and convert it to the desired file format and save it.

Comment: If you mean what i am using beside Java Spring i have my functions in pgAdmin 4 and i am using Maven

Comment: My problem is i don't know what to do in the backend with the code i have